# UITableView inside a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I need to do something like [this](http://bit.ly/16obdK6) but I've only found out how to control a UITableView by having the TableView in its on UITableViewController. How can I control a UITableView without it having it's on UITableViewController?

Comment: There's nothing special about a `UITableViewController`, it just auto-generates a `UITableView` instead of a plain `UIView` if you don't override the `loadView` method.

Comment: You put the UITableView in the containing view and implement it's delegates.

Answer (score 2):

You can put a UITableView inside any View Controller, just make sure to set the delegate and data source and implements the appropriate protocols.

As you were told, this example is actually a Split View Controller.

Answer (score 1):

That table view *does* have its own UITableViewController - it just happens that the table view controller is inside a UISplitViewController. I suggest you take a look at the [View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) to get started.